# Is there any jquery print preview that shows you the printed page without the website header & menu?

Tags: jquery, css

My web application generates reports and I need now to add the print preview functionality to these reports in order to show the user what he will print of that report and **to show him that the report will not contain the website header and menu in the printed page**.

Should I use the combination of jquery and css to do this functionality?

Comment: Why do you need jQuery? Do the users use browser? In case users use a browser, the browser's print preview itself is good enough.

Comment: @Mohammed Ali — If you need to show that the report won't contain the website header and menu, but the browser's builder in print preview shows the header and menu, then what you would be showing would be a lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create style sheet with the media type as rpint

For example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Check this out : [CSS Media Types Create Print-Friendly Pages](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm)

Comment: just add header,menu{display:none} to that stylesheet

Comment: yes, this is common practice to use media print to provide different layout for print